# *ngFor cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

Hi I have this interface

```
export interface Apartment {
  id: number;
  address: string;
  rooms: Room[];
}
```

this component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  apartment: Apartment;

constructor(...) {
  // service get call to retrieve an apartment
}

ngOnInit {}

}
```

and a template

```
<h3>{{apartment.address}}</h3>
<ul>
   <li *ngFor=let room of apartment.rooms"></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is: the address is correctly printed while chrome dev console says that cannot read property "rooms" of undefined, so in one case apartment is something in the nfFor it is undefined. I think that the apartment object is not loaded yet when call ngFor. Why? How to fix this? I'm pretty new in Angular how a component is loaded in the DOM is not too clear yet to me.

Comment: there is no apartament instance on app startup.

Comment: use `ngFor=let room of apartment?.rooms"`

Comment: Quotes missing after `*ngFor=`

Comment: @GJCode any reason why safe navigation operator was not marked as answer?

Comment: I gave you an up point because I didn't know about safe navigation, but was not marked as an answer because it didn't work for me, I think that working on view binding is better than look for null in these kind of scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an ngIf anytime you're using the value you retrieve from backend.

```
 <h3 *ngIf='apartment'>{{apartment.address}}</h3>
 <ul>
    <li *ngIf='apartment' *ngFor=let room of apartment.rooms"></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This does not work on multiple levels. You cant have 2 structural dirctives on one html element. "Only one structural directive can be applied"

Answer (score 15):

Use a safe **`navigation operator(?)`**

```
<h3>{{apartment?.address}}</h3>
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let room of apartment?.rooms"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please include the missing quote.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Much more clean. No need to wrap everything in divs/ngIfs

Answer (score 1):

You call a service to retrieve the apartment. Assuming you're retrieving from a server call, the data is not available until the call completes. It isn't a problem in your h3, because it just remains blank until the data is retrieved. The ngFor however will throw an exception as soon as it tries. The easiest fix is to put an ngIf on the ul...

```
<ul *ngIf="apartment && apartment.length">
```

This will hide the list until apartment has a value, at which point the ngFor loop will be able to complete without a problem.