# How observable works?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm learning from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dHNOWTI7H8
My service is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Schedule } from '../../../Schedule';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScheduleService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/schedules'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getSchedules(): Observable<Schedule[]> {
    console.log('get');
    return this.http.get<Schedule[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

and the call to the get function in the service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Schedule } from '../../../../Schedule';
import { ScheduleService } from 'src/app/services/schedule.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scheduler',
  templateUrl: './scheduler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scheduler.component.css']
})
export class SchedulerComponent implements OnInit {
  schedules: Schedule[] = [];
  times: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  constructor(private scheduleService:ScheduleService) {     
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.scheduleService.getSchedules().subscribe((s) => {
      console.log(s[0].weekDay);
      this.schedules = s;
    });
  }
}
```

when I use `schedule` in the html part of the component

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mun</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let s of times; index as i">
            <tr>
                <td>Slot</td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[0].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[0].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[1].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[1].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[2].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[2].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[3].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[3].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[4].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[4].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[5].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[5].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="schedules[6].times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedules[6].times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'times')`. I know the reason why I get this error and there's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502775/cant-assign-value-to-variable-using-subscribe-method-in-angular-2) to this somewhere else in this website. But

- How it worked in the video?
- The fix in the answer above didn't work for me! Why? (I created an object like `_this = this; _this.schedules = s` as in the answer but did not work).

why it worked in the video above and didn't work with me? What is the difference between my code and the video?

Comment: Forget the silly video.  Q: Would you please [Edit] your post and clarify exactly how you got the error, and what you did to correct it?  Please include the link to the  "answer to this somewhere else in this website".  Q: Do you have any additional questions on WHY it works the way it does?  If you have questions about YOUR code, then please ask.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post (adding the "html").  But it's still not enough.  Please let us know: 1) If the error still occurs in the code you posted.  Please specify the EXACT error message, and the EXACT line.  2) Do you know how to resolve the error?  3) What specific questions do you have about YOUR code, that you've POSTED?

Comment: Thank you - that helps.  SUGGESTION: try the "safe navigation operator(?)", per this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018674/421195.  ALSO: Pure speculation, but perhaps this is a "timing error", and the YouTube guy just happens to have a faster machine/faster Internet connection.  It's not worth worrying about: we need to focus on YOUR code, and make sure it's robust enough for ANY potential user.

Comment: @paulsm4 yeh yeh I've seen that link of save navigation b4, but when I use it with `schedules[0]?.times[i]` I get `Object is possibly 'undefined'`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you initialize

```js
schedules: Schedule[] = []
```

At this point there are no elements in the array. You can prevent calling a non-existent position in the array by looping over your results:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of times; index as i">
    <tr>
        <td>Slot</td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let schedule of schedules">
            <td *ngIf="schedule.times[i] !== 0" [attr.rowspan]="schedule.times[i]" class="bg-light text-dark">
                    d
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Are you sure there is an array times on the schedule object?
I noticed you have a times array as member in your component,
which you are already looping over.

If this is intended you might want to think of better naming.
This will only confuse people when reading through the code.

Additionally, there is no need to subscribe to the observable.
You can just assign the observable and use an async pipe in your template.

- This allows for OnPush Change Detection Strategy to be used.
- You will not have to worry about unsubscribing to your observable.

Example:

```js
schedules$ = this.scheduleService.getSchedules()
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let schedule of schedules$ | async">
```

Comment: Oh yeh thank you! the reason is in my interface I have `times` property but not in my fake api. That's why i'm getting undefined.